# ¿Cuál es la manera más sencilla de replicar el for de Java pero en Python?

Tags: java, python

Sabemos que el **for** en Java tiene 3 argumentos, la **inicialización**, la **condición** y el **contador**. Eso nos facilita muchas cosas porque lleva el loop por dentro de la estructura del For en Java.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Pero veo que en Python podemos usar desde un simple **for** pero sin argumentos, y mi pregunta es,

**¿Si quisiera replicar un for en Python, qué estructura debo seguir?**

**Saludos y gracias de antemano.**

Comment: No estoy seguro si es que entiendo tu pregunta bien. Pero, debes pensar, que el contador es más bien, una expresión que se ejecuta al final del cuerpo de bucle, y la condición se verifica antes de iniciar el bucle. Dicho esto, para replicarlo, podrías usar un while.. inicializar la variable antes del while, luego, la condición en la expresión del while, y al final del cuerpo, ejecutar la expresión que va en el contador

Comment: Esto lo digo para aclarar, en Python, a diferencia de Java, todo bucle for trabaja con iterables. No existe un for que haga puramente de contador. range, lo que es usado por las respuestas a la fecha de este comentario, también es un iterable.

Comment: Algo interesante respecto al tema https://sadh.life/post/cursed-for/

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

El **for** de java es mucho más que llevar un contador. Puedes tener varios contadores, con expresiones condicionales complejas y operaciones más complejas que el incremento. Ninguna de las tres partes del for es obligatoria.

Para un for tan simple como el que pones, en python es equivalente a:

```py
for i in range(0, 5):
    print(i)
```

Ésta es la forma más habitual en python que, en verdad, es más similar al `for-each` de java:

```java
for (int i: Range.between(0, 4)){
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

Para el caso más general, habría que ir a algo así en python (*pseudocódigo*):

```py
init  # inicialización
while cond:
    ... # cuerpo del bucle
    post_procesado
```

Que para el caso dado sería:

```py
i: int = 0
while i < 5:
    ...  # cuerpo del bucle
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

La forma más fácil sería utilizando `range()` que tiene máximo 3 argumentos que son valor inicial (Incluyente), valor final (Excluyente) e incremento, por lo que hacer un rango de `i = 0` hasta `i < 5` con un incremento de `1` sería:

```
range(0, 5, 1)
```

Como el valor final es excluyente entonces el rango sería: `0, 1, 2, 3 y 4`

Podrías omitir poner el valor inicial y el incremento ya que el valor inicial por defecto es 0 y el incremento 1, así que si utilizas `range()` con un solo argumento (Es decir `range(5)`) sería el valor final y utiliza como valor inicial el `0` y el incremento `1`.

Ejemplo:

```
for i in range(0, 5, 1):  # range(5) haría lo mismo
    print(i)
```

Esto imprime:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```